# Child #2 Participant Status not updating after Payment by Check (a Bug ?)

Tags: civicontribute

I have one Parent + his 2 Children registered to a paid event (via a Webform) :

- The Parent is the Webform Contact1 and Contribution holder, but has
  no event-fee to pay
- Each of the 2 children (Contact2 and 3) has an event-fee (65€ and 45€)
- A Solidarity Contribution can also be paid ("Contribution Amount" of the Contribution page) (e.g. 11€)
- I choose "pay later".

When I register, and before payment, the situation is as follows :

- Contribution total amount : 121 € (65 + 45 + 11)
- contribution_status_id = 2 (pending)
- participant_status_id : Parent : 1 (registered) ; Children : 5 (pending)

When I record the payment (by check), the situation becomes :

- contribution_status_id = 1 (completed)
- participant_status_id : Parent : 1 (registered) ;
- Children : Child 1 : 1 (registered) ; **Child 2 : 5 (still pending).**

**From my point of view, Child 2 participant status should also become 1.**

*Nota : to record the payment, I use a Contribution Profile (check# + status), next to a Contribution "update multiple participant", but I don't think that the problem is due to this specific process.*

Comment: but can you also explain what the outcome is if you do the payment via backend?

Comment: Hi Pete, what do you mean by "backend" ?

Comment: "to record the payment, I use a Contribution Profile (check# + status), next to a Contribution "update multiple participant", but I don't think that the problem is due to this specific process" - so i was wondering (but didn't explain well) if you have absolutely rule this out by just going to the Contribution record directly and setting it as Paid - or is this not possible for some reason due to it covering all 3 contacts? And is the outcome of using Webform for 3 participants different to using normal Event form for this? trying to better understand the issue you are facing to replicate it

Comment: From my point of view, the webform result is as expected, though I don't know how we can get the same result with the standard UI : I just mentionned the Webform to explain the result. The problem is in the payment process which should update the 2 children statuses and not only one. I will test a direct payment process instead of the "multiple update", just in case ...

Comment: Other test, different result : when I use the standard UI to record the payment (after a contribution search), the Parent Contribution Status is updated to "completed", while both children participant statuses remain 5 (pending from pay later).

Comment: can you replicate the latter on the demo site eg dmaster.civicrm.org?

Comment: I can access to the following demo : https://civicrm.demo.civihosting.com/ ; but I don't know how to create 3 associated participants (1 Parent + 2 Children) with the standard UI (I personally developped a Webform to do that).

Comment: can't you do it via a normal Event that is set to allow Multiple Participants

Comment: I don't know how I can, with the standard UI, get the same registration configuration as with my webform, i.e. a main registrant who carries the Contribution, with several associated participants (who carry their event-fees), whose participant_status depends upon the paid later payment of the Contribution by the main participant : as recorded in the civicrm_participant_payment table.

Comment: sorry but i am not understanding the different outcomes from doing it via pure civi v doing webform. via the UI, if you set to multiple participants, then doesnt the 'main' (ie first) registrant carry the whole contribution and therefore the 2nd and 3rd participants payments are done by the main registrant

Comment: I have defined a Test Event as accepting multiple participants, but the "Register Participant Form" accepts only one at a time (or there is sth that I don't see ?)

Comment: if an event form (front end) is set up for Multiple Participants then once you fill in first page you should get a second page for the next participant